# Custom Taxonomy Archives templates

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, archive, custom-taxonomy

I'd really like some help with Taxonoy templates and CPT , i've been trying to work this out for a week now and i'm just getting more confused , nothing i try seems to work the way i hoped?

Can anyone please explain or show me how to achieve this , i've considered paying someone to do this as i'm not a coder , i can edit working code quite happily , but cannot write it. I though this would be much easier than this.

The Detail :

I have a **Custom Post type** named - '*Machines*'

I have a **Taxonomy** attached to that named - '*Machine-types*'

Under this are 3 machine types - '*electrical*' - '*mechanical*' - '*solar*'

I would like the archive for '*machines*' to show a list of the terms under '*machine-types*' with a link to that terms archive. I don't want to show posts, just the terms as a list.

I beleive this first file would be `archive-machines.php`

Machines (`archive-machines.php`) ?

```
  -electrical
  -mechanical
  -solar
```

When i follow one of those term links I would like it to show a list of the posts under that term only with just the '*post-title*' that links to it's `single.php` (pretty standard)

What i cannot work out is , how to get all the terms under '*machine-types*' to use the same template. Most code i've seen requires you to change the name of a term , i need this to be dynamic.

My eventual goal is to use some custom fields , but at the moment i just want get the templates working and go from there.

I feel my mouth has written checks that my brain cannot cash !  Any help would be greatly appreciated ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress does not have a standard template for archiving taxonomy terms, so an archive-machines.php template would not do you any good. You would do best to create a custom page and template, and in that template use the get_terms() function to grab all the terms in the machine-types taxonomy and output your list.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

This function will return an array of term objects. From this you could get the ID, slug, name etc. In order to get the link to the term you would use the get_term_link() function.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link

Once you click on one of those terms it would access the taxonomy-machine-types.php template. These taxonomy templates are set up to display a list of posts based on the taxonomy term chosen.

Comment: Thanks , i waded through that lot a few days ago :)

Answer (score 0):

I used these 2 templates in the end , with the machine-archive.php using some custom fields.

```
<?php

/*
 * Custom WordPress Template: archive-machine
 */

// Remove stuff

remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );

// Add our custom loop

add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'machine_archive_loop' );

function machine_archive_loop() {

        $libargs=array(  
            'hide_empty'    => 1,  
            'parent'        => 0,  
            'taxonomy'      => 'machine-type');  

            $libcats=get_categories($libargs);  

            foreach($libcats as $lc){ 
                $termlink = get_term_link( $lc->slug, 'machine-type' ); 

        ?>

         <div class="row tax-list">
            <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 columns tax-img">
               <a href="<?php echo $termlink; ?>"><img src="<?php the_field('tax_image' , 'machine-type_'.$lc->term_id); ?>" alt="view range"/></a>
            </div>

            <div class="small-12 medium-8 large-9 columns tax-description">
               <h2><a  href="<?php echo $termlink; ?>"><?php echo $lc->name; ?> Range</a></h2>
               <?php the_field('tax_description', 'machine-type_'.$lc->term_id); ?><a  href="<?php echo $termlink; ?>"> ....View the range</a>
            </div>

        </div>

        <?php } 


  // use reset postdata to restore orginal query
  wp_reset_postdata();

} 



genesis();
```

this is for taxonomy-machine-type.php

```
<?php
// Remove stuff
remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );

// Add our custom loop
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'tax_archive_loop' );
 function tax_archive_loop() {

  $taxonomy = 'machine-type';
  $queried_term = get_query_var($taxonomy);
  $terms = get_terms($taxonomy, 'slug='.$queried_term);


    // Define the query
   $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'machines',
    'machine-type' => $queried_term ,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
 );

// run the query 
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $query->have_posts() ) { 

      // Start the Loop
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();  ?>

       <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
       <p><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></p>
         <div class="entry-content">   
           <?php echo the_content(); ?>
          <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> ... Find Out More</a>
        </div>

  <?php endwhile;?>

<hr/>

<?php 

}        
    // use reset postdata to restore orginal query
    wp_reset_postdata();
} 
genesis();
```